# Visual Studio 2015 hangs and then: The 'XamarinIOSPackage' package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, Community, hangs after saving any change or when opening a .cshtml view.

Can you please hint to actions that might lead to VS working again?

This problem began after I installed the following two updates / extensions:

Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.8

Ionic Project Templates extension
visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8fa5bff2-e023-4e13-8b36-0244e935fb7d

I tried:

Uninstalling the Azure update.

Uninstalling the Ionic extension.

uninstalling VS and re-installing it.

The VS ActivityLog.xml says:

```
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [XamarinIOSPackage]</description>
<guid>{77875FA9-01E7-4FEA-8E77-DFE942355CA1}</guid>
<hr>80131534</hr>
<errorinfo>The type initializer for 'Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.BuildServerAddressProvider.BuildServerAddressProvider' threw an exception.</errorinfo>
```

Comment: The problem disappeared at the end of December 2015, after I updated Xamarin by:
Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other > (stable) updates Check now > Update

Answer (score 10):

The best way to resolve this is to force the extension cache to reset. You can do this via:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Delete everything in this folder
   `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`
3. Restart Visual Studio

Thanks!